# Width and Horizontal Position Are Ambiguous

Tags: xcode, swift, constraints, ambiguous

it seems I have created a simple Image view with the following constraints:

Align Center X to: **Superview**

Align Center Y to: **Superview**

Top Space to: **Top Layout Guide**

Bottom Space to: **Bottom Layout Guide**

And I have the **Width and Horizontal Position Are Ambiguous** message. I am trying to correct it, but I am not sure about what is happening in the first place.

Do you have an idea?

Comment: you have no constraints for the width of the imageView. You could for example set the width to the width of the image.

Comment: it seems ambiguous to me as well, because I don't see any constraints which makes the _horizontal_ position clarified; you may need to add either a _width_ or a _ratio_ constraint to resolve the ambiguity.

Comment: your constraints are ambiguous. What do you want to do to the imageview. resize with the superview? or dont resize and stick to the center of the superview?

Comment: Actually, I want the view to resize, depending on the device, so I thought about linking it to the superview and let it do the resizing. Entering a fixed width wouldn't do. The width has to be dependent on the device. In the latest version of my app, I had a fixed width for each device, but there are now too many device sizes. I am trying to solve this without entering a new size each time. Is there a way to do this with constraints?

Answer (score 5):

You need to add the same constraint for left and right as you did for top and bottom.

Or set fixed width.

Answer (score 1):

Remove **Top Space to: Top Layout Guide** and **Bottom Space to: Bottom Layout Guide** constraints,
Set Image's **Width and Height** instead or **(Width + Aspect ratio)**.
Because every view needs x,y, height, width to render itself.

So You've already set X and Y using **Align Center X to: Superview** and
**Align Center Y to: Superview**. So it needs specific width and height now.

Comment: Your answer fixed my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

As you have told for constrainst:
Align Center X to: Superview

Align Center Y to: Superview

Top Space to: Top Layout Guide

Bottom Space to: Bottom Layout Guide

The left option is of width
Consider that any view which is placed behaves like expanding to and fro, we have to stablise it by putting constraints, your missing constraints for setting width (either from leading and trailing or from width) is making this issue

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Editor > Resolve Autolayout issue > Add Missing Constraint`

Then the get the solution on the error page, what needs to be updated for example refer to the image where the `height` needs to be modified to `21` from `20`

[image]